# Changing Feature and Plugin version in PDE headless build

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

Am able to successfully build a feature using PDE Headless mechanism

But after the build is successful, the version of the plugins and feature is set to 0.0.0. This is expected because, in my feature and plugins the version is set to 0.0.0.qualifier.

What am expecting is, change/update the version while PDE build takes place and this version has to be set for both the feature and plugins

Ex: after the PDE build, my feature and plugins version should be something like this

1.3.0.20140404-1150

where 1.3.5 is the value that i need to specify (or give as input) to the PDE headless build

Is it possible? If yes, please guide me to achieve this.

Any pointers in this direction is much appreciated.

NOTE: I need to update the version of both plugins and feature while PDE build takes place and its a feature build not a product build

Answer (score 0):

You can start by setting the initial versions in your source code/IDE and then use API tools to help  you stay consistent.See http://www.eclipse.org/pde/pde-api-tools/ and http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-api-tools/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. My requirement is, i need the plugins and features version to be the same. Currently, all my plugins and features are set to different versions (initial versions in the IDE). Which i don't want (i.e each plugin is having different version after pde build). So, while PDE headless build happens i want to maintain the same version for all my plugins and features, no matter what their initial version is.

can we use PDE-API tools for acheive this? 

I ran through the links and i was not able to find anything that points to version change/updating in PDE headless builds.